# Validation class hierarchy override

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

Is it possible to override the class hierarchy for hibernate/javax validation?
Or how to override the parameter validation by extending a class?

Using the `@Valid` annotation and having setup the javax validation annotations in my class. I want to have an extended class where the validation is removed.
I found that hibernate validation loops through the entire class hierarchy, and checks for validation even in the super classes.
I use this from a Json based REST API set up with Spring MVC.

Example:

```
public class Parent {
    protected Integer numChildren;

    @NotNull(message = "NumChildren has to be set.") 
    @Size(min 1, max 10, message = "A partent has to have at least one kid.")
    public Integer getNumChildren() {
        return numChildren;
    }

    public void setNumChildren(Integer numChilds) {
        this.numChildren = numChilds;
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {

    // A child doesnt have to have kids, but can, so I want to override this parameter
    // and remove the validation requirement, and make it just optional.
    @Override
    public Integer getNumChildren() {
        return super.numChildren;
    }
}
```

Best Regards,
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bean Validation does not allow to disable/change constraints in super classes. Constraints are always combined. I guess the way to go would be via groups, eg a *ParentChecks* group and a *ChildChecks* group. Assign the constraints which are specific to parent of child to the corresponding group. You can then redefine the default group for parent to be *ParentChecks*,_Parent_ and the one for child to be *ChildChecks*, *Child*. That should work.